# Derive an expression for $\epsilon=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}-\frac{dy}{dx}$ when $y=\frac{1}{(x+a)}$. Show that $\epsilon \to 0$ as $\Delta x \to0$.

Tags: limits, differential

Is my solution to the mentioned problem correct ?

If $y=\frac{1}{(x+a)} \;\;\;\; (for\; x \neq -a)\tag{1}$

$\Delta y = \frac{1}{(x+\Delta x + a)} - \frac{1}{(x+a)}$

$\Delta y = (x+\Delta x +a)^{-1} - (x+a)^{-1}$

$\Delta y = \frac{-\Delta x}{(x+a)(x+\Delta x+a)}$

$\frac {\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{-1}{(x+a)(x+\Delta x+a)} \tag{2}$

Differentiating Eq. 1 w.r.t x,

$\frac{dy}{dx}=(-1)(x+a)^{-2} \tag{3}$

As, $\epsilon= \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}-\frac{dy}{dx} \tag{4}$

Hence putting values of Eq. 2 & 3 in 4,

$\epsilon= \frac{-1}{(x+a)(x+\Delta x+a)} + \frac{1}{(x+a)^{2}}$

$\epsilon= \frac{1}{(x+a)}\left[\frac{-1}{(x+\Delta x+a)} + \frac{1}{(x+a)} \right]$

Finally,

$\epsilon= \frac{\Delta x}{(x+a)^{2}(x+\Delta x+a)} \;\;\;\; (for\; x \neq -a) \tag{5}$

Hence as $\Delta x \to 0, \epsilon \to 0$

The answer of the question is written in the book as below (which doesn't match with my answer):

$\epsilon= \frac{(x+a)(\Delta x)}{(x+a)(x+\Delta x+a)} \tag{6}$

Comment: It's obvious by the definition of derivative right??

Comment: Your last line seems to have problems if the factor $(x+\Delta x+a)$ in the denominator is also going to zero.  ... or if the factor $(x+a)$ is already zero...

Comment: Note that the problem can much more clearly explained via non standard Analysis. The required limit is same thing as, $\operatorname{sh}(\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{dy}{dx})$, which is $0$. We got $0$ inside the shadow part function because we took infinitesimals right in our expression.

Comment: @EricTowers only $\Delta x$ goes to zero which implies $\epsilon$ also goes to zero. I don't understand your question.

Comment: Where did you require $x \neq -a$?

Comment: As $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$, the value of the expression $x+\Delta x + a$, which clearly depends on $\Delta x$, is also changing and may or may not have a limit...

Comment: @EricTowers I do not require $x \neq -a$, but this is the only possibility for denominator to be become zero. I guess from the equation I do not get the required result which is if $\Delta x$ approaches zero, so is $\epsilon$ goes to zero.

Comment: @RAHUL Trying to understand your point of view.

Comment: I think my resulting equation (5) has a problem. May be I did some step wrong.

Comment: The idea you seem to want to use is that a fraction is zero if its numerator is zero.  That's almost true.  It's incomplete if the numerator *and* denominator are both zero.  So, how do you know whether in the limit as $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$ you have $(\rightarrow 0)/(\rightarrow \neq 0)$ or $(\rightarrow 0)/(\rightarrow 0)$?  Remember **every** derivative you have ever taken has been a $[0/0]$ form in a limit, so $(\rightarrow 0)/(\rightarrow 0)$ can give any value, depending on the details of how the numerator and denominator are approaching zero.

Comment: @EricTowers If numerator i.e., $\Delta x$ goes to zero, except when $x \neq -a$, all other values will go to zero which implies that $\epsilon$ also goes to zero. So I think I need to add after equation (5) that "only if $x \neq -a$".

Comment: I might put "$x \neq -a$" right after (1), since that's the first time we see that we shouldn't be thinking about $x = -a$.  But then you should write appropriate words when computing $\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta x}{(x+a)^2(x+\Delta x+a)}$.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo in the last line? The $(x+a)$ can just cancel out.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Yes it looks like a typo or misprint in the book. But I have no way to verify it's a typo or not. If somebody can confirm my solution is correct than I can assume that book answer is a typo error.

Comment: @RAHUL It is obvious but the excercise in the book explains the difference in between $\Delta y$ and $dy$ and how a term $\epsilon$ defined as difference of both derivatives can prove that $\Delta x$ goes to zero faster than the $dx$ hence making $\epsilon$ to be zero as well.

Comment: @SalzEngineering, I think you didn't get my point. I was talking about non standard Analysis and it seems that book is completely based on standard Analysis. By the question I thought it was a question related to non standard Analysis. So the thing is ,you are true. It's not obvious. I mentioned that you need to learn non standard Analysis completely in order to understand clear and intuitive meaning of not only this question but entire math which depends on idea of infinitesimals

Comment: @Salz: It, for sure, is a typo. All your steps are correct.

Comment: @RAHUL Ok, I'm not familiar with "non-standard analysis" at the moment. Will look into it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ultralegend5385: That's great. Your help is appreciated.